# How to activate WpMediaElement in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement

I would like to use the plug-in WPMediaElement for styling audio player in Word Press. As I understand it should be default installed in WordPress (I am using version 5.2.15) and it is also placed in the folder wp-includes/js/mediaelement. But it is not included when the website are showing in a browser :-|

What do I have to do for activating it?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that medialement is loaded on all the pages.
Insert this in your child-theme functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
}, 100);
```